# Multidimensional Array in a Cell in a TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm calling a multidimensional array like this:

```
Guide* guideColumnOne = [[multiArraysOfGuides objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The problem is it crashes with a EXC_BREAKPOINT error.
The guide is set like this in another method:

```
multiArraysOfGuides = [self seperateGuides:[appDelegate getGuideList] intoArrays:3];
```

The seperateGuides works as I can check the value and it is correct in the same method as it is created.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Is EXC_BREAKPOINT the only error? Have you tried before that statement to print the multi dimensional array with an NSLog?

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, you're probably going to have to `retain` the multiArraysOfGuides :)

Comment: (and I'm assuming that indexPath.row is definitely within range of the array at index 0 of multiArraysOfGuides!)

Comment: I'm not using arc, so that could be one thing.

Comment: Retain did it. Could you do an answer so I could accept it?, so you get the rep ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deanWonbourne gave the answer in the comments.
I had to retain multiArraysOfGuides, to fix the problem.